# Are characters classes allowed in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

Are character classes supported in ANTLR 4 lexers? I saw some examples that looked like this is OK:

`LITERAL: [a-zA-z]+;`

but what I found is that it matches the string "OR[" with the opening bracket. Using ranges worked:

`LITERAL: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;`

and only identified "OR" as the LITERAL. Here is an example:

```
grammar Test;

@members {
  private void log(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
  }
}

parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : atom                   {log("atom(" + $atom.text + ")");}
 | l=expr OR r=expr       {log("IOR:left(" + $l.text + ") right(" + $r.text + "}");}
 | (OR '[' la=atom ra=atom ']') {log("POR:left(" + $la.text + ") right(" + $ra.text + "}");}
 ;

atom
 : LITERAL
 ;

OR      : O R ;

LITERAL: [a-zA-z]+;
//LITERAL: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

fragment O: ('o'|'O');
fragment R: ('r'|'R');
```

When given the input "OR [ cat dog ]" it parses correctly, but "OR[ cat dog ]" does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use character sets in ANTLR 4 lexers, but the ranges are case sensitive. You used `[a-zA-z]` where I believe you meant `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: Holy cow, I can't believe how many times I looked at that and didn't notice the case was wrong. It might be time for new glasses. Thanks, 280Z28.